# Re-installation failed due to different application signatures

Tags: android, debugging, code-signing

I am getting the above error message when I try to debug an application that is already installed. Most others who run into this seem to be developing on different machines with different key files, but I am doing everything on the same box.

My issue is that I am testing my database upgrade process (i.e. what the onUpgrade() method of my SQLiteOpenHelper extension does). For this, I would like to try the upgrade on top of a variety of older builds. These builds are available as signed application packages. When I deploy such a package to a fresh emulator and then try to debug the current version on top, I get the error in the subject line. I think that this is because the debug deployment packages are unsigned, and the currently installed package is signed. Again, I know that the error goes away if I unstall the currently installed app, but then I cannot test the upgrade.

I do not want to go through the effort of switching back my dev environment to older build versions, so that I can build unsigned packages for these versions. I may not even be able to do this, because I switched source code repositories recently and lost some of the history.

I believe that if I were able to get Eclipse to generate a signed package for debugging, it should work. Alternatively, I could manually deploy a signed package and launch a debug session without a build/deployment step, but I have not been to figure out if this is possible, either. What can I do?

Edit: The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#setup) was helpful in figuring out how to sign a package with the debug key, but this does not help me, because I need to debug with a private key. I suppose that this is not possible.

Comment: you should generate them all with one signature - otherwise it wont work. only uninstall and fresh install will work with different signatures. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign current package with release key, install on device, run the application and connect debugger in Eclipse. How to connect debugger: in the DDMS perspective on the Devices view select your application and press button with "green bug":

[image]

Comment: perfect perfect. the only problem is that my app force-closes when it starts (and an older database is present). with a fast click I was able to get into a breakpoint, though. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post it as an answer:

You should generate them all with one signature - otherwise it wont work. only uninstall and fresh install will work with different signatures. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html also taken from there:

**Eclipse Users**
*If you are developing in Eclipse/ADT (and have set up Keytool and Jarsigner as described above in Basic Setup for Signing), signing in debug mode is enabled by default. When you run or debug your application, ADT signs the .apk with the debug certificate, runs zipalign on the package, then installs it on the selected emulator or connected device. No specific action on your part is needed, provided ADT has access to Keytool.*

Comment: Sergey, I figured that out, but I cannot resign my older packages with the debug key, nor can I recreate them. Looks like I am out of luck and will have to find the reason for why my upgrade fails without the help of the debugger.

Comment: @cdonner you can use commandline `adb shell` then type `logcat` and see where it fails too